# Removing Ignite tables not deleting the data from persistence layer

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I've configured 3 node Ignite Cluster with Persistence enabled. Now, when I'm dropping a table from SQL line, its dropped. However underlying cache dir in disk is still showing and not deleted from all cluster nodes. Do I need to delete the cache dir for each table manually from each node after it dropped?

I want the once table has been dropped, the underlying cache dir also need to be removed.

Comment: DROP TABLE should destroy the cache in case it was created with CREATE TABLE. Could you please describe how are you creating the table and dropping it step by step with the configuration, and what is the current content in the cache directory?

Comment: @antkr Create Table Statement and DROP statement

CREATE TABLE City (
  ID INT(11),
  Name CHAR(35),
  CountryCode CHAR(3),
  District CHAR(20),
  Population INT(11),
  PRIMARY KEY (ID, CountryCode)
) WITH "backups=2, CACHE_NAME=City";

drop table city

Comment: I have checked it and files were removed. Directory remained intact. Is it a problem for you? Why?

Comment: @alamar you are correct. All files are removed though cache directory intact. So I need to remove manually the directories for dropped caches? In addition, if I will not delete the dir and use the same name when creating the cache will it use the same dir to store the files on disk?

Comment: I guess so. Why do you need to remove them? How Ignite stores its data is an implementation detail.

Comment: @alamar To clean it properly from disks as well

Comment: Why do you need to clean it?

Comment: @alamar as I said just want to clean the cache dir from disk as well.

Comment: What happens in db/ is internal details of implementation of Apache Ignite and you should not need doing anything there.